# edit word document in windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

how I can edit word document in windows 8.1 application  .

I have made it in windows form by using system.IO

so what I can do in windows application 
I need to make function to find and replace words

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `.Docx` formatted word documents there is nothing built in to .NET that will let you edit the documents. However there is a extra library created by Microsoft you can download called the "[OpenXML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)" that will let you edit the documents via code.